# Need to constantly monitor serial data in Python

Tags: python, serial-port

Right now I am using an Arduino to send data from an analog sensor to COM4. I am trying to make a python script that continuously monitors that data and looks for a certain parameter.

I tried something like this but it isn't alerting me correctly

```
import serial
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

port = "COM4"
ser = serial.Serial(port,9600)
value = 0

while 1:
    value = ser.read()
    if value > 400:
        tkMessageBox.showwarning(
            "Open file",)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can we have an example of what it's doing vs. what you expect?

Comment: Well I am running it in the Wing Python Shell and it just stays at "Evauluating blablah.py" - it never actually outputs any values. Then when I unplug the USB from the arduino the values come up. As if they didn't register until I did that.

Comment: Assuming that ser.read() actually returns Tkinter isn't going to show anything unless Tkinter.Frame(...Tk()...).mainloop() is called.

Answer (score 3):

If the `serial` package you are using is [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/), take note of the definition of the [`Serial.read()` method](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read):

> `read(size=1)`
>
> Parameter: size – Number of bytes to read.
>
> Returns:   Bytes read from the port.
>
> Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.
>
> Changed in version 2.5: Returns an instance of *bytes* when available (Python 2.6 and newer) and *str* otherwise.

Although you are trying to process `byte` objects, you may (depending on Python version) be handling `str` or `bytes` (array) objects. These objects do not necessarily correspond to integer values.

Even when receiving `byte` objects from `read()`, the largest unsigned integer will be 255.
Comparing `value` with 400 doesn't make sense. Try to find the type of the returned objects with a simple debugging output.

```
print type(value)
```

If you need to handle an `str` object, check the use of [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) for convertion.

(The `flush` suggestion refers to the original question, which used `print`, not `tkinter`).

See [how-to-flush-output-of-python-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print), and try the command line shell, not the IDE which may affect output buffering.

Comment: It isn't even catching my conditional when I don't print it out :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the Arduino code relay all the analog values to COM4, have it relay a flag only when you meet the conditional.

So arduino code could be:

```
void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  if (sensorValue >= 400){
    Serial.print("1"); // 1 will be the flag that will be sent to COM4
  }
```

Then your Python code can just look for the flag like this:

```
import serial
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

port = "COM4"
ser = serial.Serial(port,9600)
value = 0


while 1:
    value = ser.read();
    print value
    if value == "1":
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("BLAH", "BLAH\n")
        exit()
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/), `serial.read()` only reads one byte, which means a maximum value of 255. If your Arduino is sending string values back it's probably best to separate them with newline characters and use `serial.readline()`.

Unless you have specific performance requirements sending strings back from the Arduino will make debugging significanly easier anyway.

Also if you are receiving strings back from the Arduino, your test should be `if int(value) > 400:`